# Why is the string of a variable redirected to a file with trailing space and not correct displayed after read from file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to work with batch, but I'm having some bugs that I didn't have before making similar applications.

First issue:

I'm using `set /p` to prompt for a string, then I save it to a file using

```
ECHO Myvar>"%systemroot%\name.ini"
```

That works fine, but when I open the file `name.ini` there is a space after the string I typed. I built already a batch in the past using this and it didn't happen.

Second issue:

When I load the file to string, it doesn't work. Something happens to the string that if I try to output it using

```
ECHO %Myvar%
```

the output is `ECHO is off`. As I said before, I used this once already in a different batch file and it worked fine.

Example code:

```
@ECHO OFF
if not exist "%systemroot%\asd.ini" (
    set /p asd= COMR: 
    ECHO %asd%>"%systemroot%\asd.ini"
    REM Save the string to a file
) else (
    set /p asd=<"%systemroot%\asd.ini"
    REM Read the string
    ECHO %asd%
    pause
)
```

P.S: I already tried using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: did you remember to use `!asd!` instead of `%asd%` after you added `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`?

Comment: LMAO I f'cking spent one and a half hour trying to figure what I did wrong and was just that... I feel so dumb right now :P Thaks dude, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist "%systemroot%\asd.ini" (
set /p asd= COMR: 
ECHO !asd!>"%systemroot%\asd.ini"
REM Save the string to a file
) else (
set /p asd=<"%systemroot%\asd.ini"
REM Read the string
ECHO !asd!

)
pause
```

Stuff in brackets are treated as one line.

I removed `Echo Off` - hiding messages is not a good idea when you have a problem.